# Python basic nested statements and scope concept

Tags: python, scope, nested-function

```
def func():
    def nested():
        global x
        x = 1
x = 2
func()
print(x)
```

The correct answer would be '2' and the reason why is because func() is not defined. But when I read this it seems that func() is defined as nested(). I would think that when you call func() that would then automatically call nested(). I'm struggling to grasp this and understand why I shouldn't read it that way.

Comment: `nested` gets created *but not called.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining `nested` inside `func`, but you're not calling `nested()` anywhere in `func`, so when you call `func()` it's effectively doing nothing.

To do what you want try defining `func` as:

```
def func():
    def nested():
        global x
        x = 1
    nested()
```

**UPDATE**: After StevenRumbalski's comment, I think a small addition about what exactly is going on in that function can help clarify things around.

Python's functions are themselves objects which can respond to the operator `()`.
When you define a new function, what you're actually doing is instantiating a function object and giving it a name. In the example above, `def func()` creates a function instance and gives it name func, so that when you apply operator `()` to func (i.e. when you call the function with `func()`) the code of the function associated to that name is executed.

Let's now take one step further and look at what happens with `nested`.
Nested is defined **inside func's scope**, so when you exit func's scope *the name nested* is not defined anymore.
If, however, you **return the function object** to the caller of `func`, you can use that object to run `nested`'s code.

A small example:

```
def returning_func():
    def nested():
        print("I am nested!")
    return nested # note the lack of the () operator!
```

In this case, if we do

```
my_reference_to_nested = func()
```

nothing gets printed, because nested is defined but not executed.
If we call it, however:

```
my_reference_to_nested()
```

we execute nested's code and print to the output `I am nested!`

Comment: I see! So func() is defining nested() but not actually calling it. That makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it cleared things up ;) If that works for you, make sure to accept the answer so that it gets marked as solved :)

Comment: Or `return nested` then call `func` as `func()()`.  Or then call `func` as `inner_func = func()` then `inner_func()` where `inner_func` ends up being an alias for `nested`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski o_O

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I think that might read a bit confusing to someone who's not familiar with python's functions as objects. Maybe I can expand my answer a bit...